# understanding Session.Delete Fluent Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose we have the following entities:

```
public class plaserv
{
    public virtual int id { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<plaattach> adjuntos { get; set; }
    public plaserv()
    {
        adjuntos = new List<plaattach>();
    }
}

public class plaattach
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual plaserv plaserv { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(500)]
    public virtual string destination_name { get; set; }
}
```

We also have a couple of repositories such as the following:

```
public class PlaServRepository
{
    private SessionHelper _sessionHelper;
    public PlaServRepository(SessionHelper sessionHelper)
    {
        _sessionHelper = sessionHelper;
    }
    public void Delete(plaserv entity)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = _sessionHelper.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _sessionHelper.Session.Delete(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

and

```
public class PlaAttachRepository
{   
 ....
    public void Delete(plaattach entity)
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = _sessionHelper.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _sessionHelper.Session.Delete(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Furthermore, the model was created using automapping, as you can see the association between plaattach plaserv and is one to many. Now supposing I want to delete a table row plaattach, because when you run `_sessionHelper.Session.Delete (entity)` from the repository PlaattachRepository not only PlaattachRepository deleted row in the table but also plaattach in plaserv row?

I hope explain correctly

Comment: UPDATE: Automapping not include the cascade convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really stupid, and obviously very a rookie, my class really implemented a cascade delete convention.
When making the following change, everything worked correctly

```
    public void Apply(IManyToOneInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.None();
    }
```